# How can i customize the output of "repeat rule" for human readability (german)?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I'm using the Calendar Module, which comes with a date-repeat feature. Showing the "repeat rule" in a view results in e.g.

> Wiederholungen jede Woche jeden Mittwoch !repeats_every_interval, 10
>   mal .

which is rather unacceptable. Is there a way to rewrite the output of this? Which replacement patterns do i have to use to reproduce the repeat rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by just deleting the phrase by hand from the localized translation set.

I hope this won't trigger any other unwanted stuff.